# Advice on RXJS usage in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I am learning to be a full stack developer and have been building out an application using Node JS as a backend. Since I have lots of experience using Angular I love RxJS as it makes everything more concise and easy. So naturally I was tempted to use RxJS for some types of tasks. Are there any down sides to using RxJS on the backend, more specifically are there any downs sides I can learn about from the following code?

***Invite Route:***

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  if (req.headers.data) {
    return services.InviteService.authenticateInvite(req.headers.data)
      .subscribe(
        _res => {
          // Return options for front end.
          // If string the invite code was not found.
          // If null the associated email was not a user account.
          // If user the associated email was found.
        },
        _error => {
          // Some stuff when wrong...
        }
      );
  } else {
    // return some sort of error code.
  }

});
```

***Invite Service:***

```
class InviteService  {

  constructor(models) {
    this.models = models
  }

  findInviteById(id) {
    return Observable.defer(() => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.models.Invite.findOne({
        where: { inviteId: id }
      }));
    });
  }

  findUserById(email) {
    return Observable.defer(() => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.models.User.findOne({
        where: { email: email }
      }));
    });
  }

  authenticateInvite(token) {
    let payload = jwt.verify(token, appConfig.SESSION_SECRET);

    return this.findInviteById(payload.inviteId)
      .map(_invite => _invite ? _invite : Observable.of('Invalid Invite ID'))
      .mergeMap(_invite => _invite._isScalar ? _invite : this.findUserById(payload.email));
  }
}

module.exports = InviteService;
```

As you can see in the Invite Service I have used the Observable stream to first check if the Invite id is valid and then it checks if the recipient id is found in the database as a current user account. From either of the three returned values I can now tell the front end what it must do.

I really like RxJS but I am just learning NodeJS and really do not know if this will be problematic.

Comment: That's a really cool idea! This will probably end up getting closed as Primarily Opinion-Based for *this site, however,* I would suggest posting this to [CodeReview.se] since your code does work and you're soliciting advice on specific implementation with code. You'll get some very well-elaborated responses there, just make sure to reformat the question to conform to their community https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask (like, use as a title "Using RxJS Observables to mediate routes in nodejs" or something).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: There's no reason not to use RxJS anywhere it makes sense to.

Comment: If anyone is interested I posted a version of this question on Code Review per the advice of msanford.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187586/using-rxjs-observables-to-mediate-routes-in-nodejs